# Why do I get ambiguous error

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In Windows 8 it worked fine.
When I upgraded it to Windows 8.1 I got an error:

```
Error   1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(System.IO.Stream)' and 'EventHandler.UI.Extensions.StreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(System.IO.Stream)'...
```

Here is my Method that gets the error:

```
public BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(byte[] imageByteArray)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImg = new BitmapImage();
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray);

    var randomAccessStream = memStream.AsRandomAccessStream(); //This line has error.
    bitmapImg.SetSourceAsync(randomAccessStream);

    return bitmapImg;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove one of using statement for methods and use the full signature

Comment: What is the `EventHandler.UI.Extensions.StreamExtensions` namespace?

Comment: Or use the full namespace for `AsRandomAccessStream` instead like `System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream`. I asume this function existed before the update, over the UI.Extensions namespace.

Comment: Consider removing either of the `using` _directives_ (not statements) `using System.IO;` and `using EventHandler.UI.Extensions;` in top of file. Can depend on whether you have `using`s outside or insider `namespace` declaration if the namespace of your class is related, but I don't think it is relevant here because in that case there would be no ambiguity (one of the extensions would have higher "priority").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your problem by using the full namespace:

```
  var randomAccessStream = 
     System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(memStream);
```

As it's an extension method, you can call it the way the code shows.

Answer (score 2):

What is going on is that `AsRandomAccessStream` exists in more than one namespace being in scope . The compiler can't know which one you are referring to. You have two options:

- Remove the namespace that you do not need that also contains `AsRandomAccessStream`
- Specify the complete path to `AsRandomAccessStream` like `System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream`

My guess is that `EventHandler.UI.Extensions.StreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream` was possibly added by the update and `System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream` is the one you were using already.

`AsRandomAccessStream` is an extension method, and you can't *cast* a method to some namespace. So you can't do something like `object.ExtensionMethod() from MyNameSpace.ExtensionMethods` or so, for as far I know... If it is actually possible, I would like to know myself! So you can only call this extension method like any other regular static class method.

Little example code never hurts:

```
    using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example NewExample = new Example();
            //NewExample.DoSomething(); //Ambiguous error
            ExtensionClass1.DoSomething(NewExample); //OK
        }
    }

    public class Example
    {

    }

    public static class ExtensionClass1
    {
        public static void DoSomething(this Example A)
        {
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionClass2
    {
        public static void DoSomething(this Example A)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (to last paragraph) Both extension methods extend the same class `System.IO.Stream`, so when the classes holding the methods are both in scope, there is no way of specifying which extension to use. Of course if they extended different types, there could be hope that `((SpecialStream)memStream).AsRandomAccessStream()` would be unambiguous.